# Passing React setState function from useState hook into a non React utility function file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Let's say I have a React functional component, `FuncComponent`, which contains a method like `logout`. However, I also have a utility method class which performs most of the primary auth login and logout API calls and logic. In my functional component, I mainly want to just call the `logout` method in the utility file; however, I also want to clear some state along with making the API call. I know I can just do this directly in the React component itself, but I'm a bit curious - can I pass my functional component `setState` method into the utility function so that all of the log out action is composed into a single function?

I tried something like this, which didn't work:

```
// React Component A
const [libraryState, setLibraryState] = useState(...);
...

const logoutOfLibrary = () => {
     AuthHelper.logoutOfLibrary(setLibraryState, libraryState);
}
```

```
// Auth Helper - NOT a React component, just an assortment of utility functions.
const logoutOfLibary(
    clearLibaryStateCallback: (libraryState: LibraryState) => void, 
    libraryState: LibraryState
) => {
    // ...logout actions

    // creating an object with cleared auth state, like so: { loggedIn: false, userId: undefined, ... }
    const clearedStateObject = defaultStateObject;
    
    clearLibraryStateCallback(clearedStateObject)
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem/error?

Comment: There's no error - the problem is that it's doesn't seem to be actually using "setLibraryState". It doesn't fail or anything, my app state just doesn't update after logging out.